# Group by, sort, merge in a Object that contains multi array

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, object

I have an object that contains 2 arrays that I want to handle by JavaScript

[image: original object]

Or

```
{Array1: Array(11), Array2: Array(11)}

Array1:(11) ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'E']

Array2:(11) ['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2']
```

My question is :

How can I group and sort that object to be like this

[after group and sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkaWN.png)

Then get top 3 rows by value with the rest that are merged in 1 row like:

[image: final result]

I did the same with python combine with SQL but don't know how to do the same by using JavaScript only, here is what I did:

Add data to data frame which is already grouped and sorted in SQL

```
df1 = collection_condition(Grouped table)
```

Create new data frame - df2 -that contains top 3 from df1

```
df2 = df1.iloc[3:]
```

Create new data frame - df3 - that contains the rest from df1

```
df3 = df1.iloc[:3]
```

Then calculate total of value of df3

```
rest_total = df3["Array2"].sum()
```

Then add new line to df2

```
df2.loc[-1] = ["Others", rest_total]
df2.index = df2.index + 1 
df2 = df2.sort_index()
```

My plan here is:

1. Try to group by that object (optional - you don't need to answer this one as I can manage to have a grouped object but any solution would be good as well)
2. Have to sort that object so that I can cut it like I did with python or any suggest will be good as well.

Thanks

Comment: Look into reduce, map, filter

Comment: I can't understand the logic of sorting in the first part. How `3` is after `1`?

Comment: @MaheerAli that my mistake sorry

Comment: Do you need an implementation in Python or only JS?

Comment: @Samleo JS only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transpose the data, group it, sort it and get the top three values and the summed other values, transpose again and assign back to the object.

```js
const
    transpose = (r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]),
    group = (r, a) => {
        var temp = r.find(v => v[1] === +a[1]);
        if (!temp) {
            r.push([a[0], +a[1]]);
        } else {
            temp[1] += +a[1];
        }
        return r;
    }

var data = { Array1: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'E'], Array2: ['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2'] },
    temp = Object
        .values(data)
        .reduce(transpose, [])
        .reduce(group, [])
        .sort(({ 1: a }, { 1: b }) => b - a)
        .reduce((r, a, i) => r.concat([i < 4 ? a : ['OTHERS', r.pop()[1] + a[1]]]), [])
        .reduce(transpose, []);

[data.Array1, data.Array2] = temp;

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: E should be 10 i think?

Comment: Thank for the correct answer, it look hard to digest though

Answer (score 0):

To do it in **JavaScript**, you can use combine the 2 arrays into an array of 2 objects, and then sort the arrays using the `.sort()` [method](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp).

```js
var a1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'E'];
var a2 = ['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2'];

function sortTable(){
    //Combine the 2 arrays into an array of objects
    //This is assuming that both arrays are of the same length.
    var i, table = [];
    for(i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
        table.push({
            //I'm assuming you are sorting numbers, so I use parseInt()
            "sorting":parseInt(a2[i]), //if a1 is the array you need to sort by, replace a2 with a1.
            "name":a1[i]
        });
    }
    
    //This is where the "magic" (sorting) happens
    table.sort(function(a,b){
        return b.sorting-a.sorting; //descending order
        //return parseInt(a.sorting)-parseInt(b.sorting); //ascending order
    });
    
    //At this point, your table is sorted in descending order
    //table[0] is your highest value.
    
    //EDIT: OOPS forgot to add merging
    var sum = 0;
    var nToDisplay = 3; //change accordingly
    var mergedTable = []; //creating a new table so that you still will have your original table
    for(i=0;i<nToDisplay;i++){
        mergedTable.push(table[i]);
    }
    
    for(i=nToDisplay;i<table.length;i++){
        sum+=table[i].sorting;
    }
    mergedTable.push({
        "sorting":sum,
        "name":"OTHERS"
    });

    //FOR OUTPUT
    out='<div><b>MERGED TABLE</b><br>';
    for(i=0;i<mergedTable.length;i++){
        out += mergedTable[i].name+" | "+mergedTable[i].sorting+"<br>";
    }
    out+="</div><hr />";
    
    out+='<div><b>ORIGINAL TABLE</b><br>';
    for(i=0;i<table.length;i++){
        if(i<3) out+="<b>";
        out += table[i].name+" | "+table[i].sorting+"<br>";
        if(i<3) out+="</b>";
    }
    out+="</div>";
    
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = out;
}
```

```html
<h3>Array values:</h3>
<div>
  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'E']</div>
<div>
  ['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2']</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Sort my table!" onclick="sortTable()"/>
</div>

<div><hr /></div>

<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible option in **Python**, given the arrays:

```
ari1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'E']
ari2 = ['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2']
```

Build a dict to calculate the sum for each letter:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tmp = defaultdict(int)
for a, b in zip(ari1, ari2):
 tmp[a] += int(b)

print(tmp)
#=> defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'A': 6, 'B': 7, 'C': 8, 'D': 3, 'E': 10, 'F': 6, 'G': 9})
```

Then build a sorted list, since dictionaries doesn't hold order:

```
sorted_tmp = sorted([ [k, v] for k,v in tmp.items() ], key = lambda x: -x[1] )
print(sorted_tmp)
#=> [['E', 10], ['G', 9], ['C', 8], ['B', 7], ['A', 6], ['F', 6], ['D', 3]]
```

Then slice the list and build the final result:

```
res = sorted_tmp[0:3] + [[ 'others', sum([x[1] for x in sorted_tmp[3:]]) ]]
#=> [['E', 10], ['G', 9], ['C', 8], ['others', 22]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following steps.

1. use `map()` to get an array of `objects` which contains both number and letter.
2. Sort the array of object on the basis of `num` using `sort()`
3. Get the part of array below 3 using `slice()`
4. Add the values of that part using `reduce()`
5. At last join the reduced part(part after row 3) with first 3 elements using `concat()`
6. And then change the **array of objects** to an **object of two arrays** using `reduce()`

```js
let obj = {arr1:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'E'],arr2:['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2']};
let temp = obj.arr2.map((num,i) => ({num:num,letter:obj.arr1[i]})).sort((a,b) => b.num - a.num);
/**/
let rowNumber = 3;
let merged = temp.slice(0,3).concat(temp.slice(3).reduce((ac,item) => ({num:Number(item.num) + Number(ac.num), letter:ac.letter + item.letter})));
merged = merged.reduce((ac,a) => {
  ac.arr1.push(a.letter)
  ac.arr2.push(a.num)
  return ac;
},{arr1:[],arr2:[]})
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'E']
var b = ['5', '7', '4', '3', '8', '1', '9', '1', '5', '4', '2']

var hsh = creteHashFromArrays(a, b)
hsh = sortArrayDescending(hsh)
hsh = iterateHash(hsh)
console.log(hsh)

function creteHashFromArrays(a, b) {
    var h = {};
    for(ele in a) {
        if (a[ele] in h) {
            h[a[ele]] = h[a[ele]] + parseInt(b[ele])
        } else {
            h[a[ele]] = parseInt(b[ele])
        }
    }
    return h;
}

function sortArrayDescending(h) {
    var r = {}
    Object.keys(h).sort(function(a,b){return h[b] - h[a]}).map(k => r[k] = h[k])
    console.log(r)
    return r;
}

function iterateHash(r) {
    result = {}
    var x = Object.keys(r)
    for(i in x){

        if (i < 3) {
            result[x[i]] = r[x[i]]
        } else {
            if ("others" in result) {
                result["others"] = parseInt(result["others"]) + parseInt(r[x[i]])
            } else {
                result["others"] = parseInt(r[x[i]])
            }
        }
    }
    var obj = {
        "array_one": Object.keys(result),
        "array_two":  Object.values(result)
    }
    console.log(obj)
    return result;
}
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gaurav24592/gt9n8k5z/2/)